# Excel external workbooks

Tags: excel

I'm trying to reference an external workbook but have run into a snag.

I've done this in the past with no issue.

In my \MASTER.xlsx I have a cell referencing another file \othersheets\SLAVE.xlsx

```
MASTER.xlsx A2 contains ='\\othersheets\[SLAVE.xlsx]05-09-22'!$B$17
```

Every time I want to change the reference point in MASTER.xlsx I receive a dialogue box prompting me to update the values.

i.e.

```
MASTER.xlsx A2 contains ='\\othersheets\[SLAVE.xlsx]12-09-22'!$B$17
```

I have tried

- Options>Advanced>General>Ask to update automatic links
- Options>Trust Centre>Trust Center Settings>External Content>Enable automatic update for all Workbook Links (not recommended)
- Options>Trust Centre>Trust Center Settings>External Content>Enable all Data Connections (not recommended)
- Data>Edit Links>Don't display the alert and don't update automatic links
- Data>Edit Links>Don't display the alert and update links
- Naming my reference sheet as a name, not a number
- Putting the workbook and reference book in the same directory
- Chaning dynamic referencing (INDIRECT) to static
- Tried saving as a Macro enabled file:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
   Appplication.DisplayAlerts=False
```

```
Sub terfuge()
   If Application.DisplayAlerts Then
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Else
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      End If
   End Sub
```

I've successfully referenced external workbooks in the past without having to update the source. And I wouldn't mind doing the odd one but I have thousands of entries. Clicking Cancel or X stops the process dead in it's tracks.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanx for reading,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Excel and that seemed to do the trick.